# Kotlin top-level function scopes & shadowing

Tags: function, scope, kotlin

Let's say I write a Kotlin package containing the following code:

```
package CoolWithATwist

// code that solves the TSP in linear time followed by this:

fun <T> println(x: T) {
    kotlin.io.println(x)
    haltAndCatchFire()  // or any annoying/destructive function
}
```

Should the package be distributed in bytecode form, am I correct in assuming that Kotlin's rules on default importing of standard library modules as per [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html) and that subsequently importing another module such as CoolWithATwist will in fact shadow the standard library auto-included println function and thus the above code will execute should the user actually call println?

What is the best way of detecting this since Kotlin compiler doesn't warn about shadowing global functions or about having to explicitly name which function you're actually calling, nor does the Kotlin plugin on IntelliJ Idea (as of version 1.1.3) or, to the best of my Knowledge, Android Studio, say anything about it?

Comment: 1. You could just test it. 2. What is `module CoolWithATwist`? Do you mean `package CoolWithATwist`? You need to import classes and functions to use them. If you do, then you *choose* to use that function. Nothing prevents you from defining a class List, that shadows the kotlin List class for example. And that in fact happens all the time. The JDK has two List classes for example, and many other classes share the same name.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I do, thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, but in Java, for example, you need to explicitly state which class/method you're using. Not so in Kotlin. If you `import CoolWithATwist.*` you're potentially hiding the println function(s) without meaning to do so.

Comment: Just as if you use `import java.awt.*;`. But star imports are a bad practice for a good reason.

Comment: Agreed. But it's a bit hard to argue that when the default in IntelliJ IDEA is to use * imports on 5 imports from a package.

Comment: I hate that, too. That's one of the things I disable in the preferences.

Comment: But the thing is, in Java, as far as I know, when you have two functions with the same name from two different packages in scope, you always get asked which one you want to use. 
That doesn't seem to happen here. If you import CoolWithATwist.*, the IDE does not ask if you want to use CoolWithATwist.println() or kotlin.io.println() 
That is what seems a bit weird to me. Mind you, I'm by no means a Java expert, so I might be wrong with respect to how the imports work, but I have seen IntelliJ asking me a lot which one to use. It doesn't do it in this case.

Comment: @Irene hi,  the rule you have mentioned above also applied in Kotlin. but Kotlin uses import statement both as import & static import.

Answer (score 7):

let's say you have the following classes in your source folders:

```
kotlin
|
|---- CoolWithATwist
|        |
|        |--- function.kt which contains your own println() function
|        |
|        |--- test1.kt (no imports)
|        |
|        |--- test2.kt (import kotlin.io.println)
|        |
|        |--- test.kt (import kotlin.io.*)
|        |
|        |___ NestedPackage
|                   |
|                   |___ test3.kt (no imports)
|
|____ main.kt
```

the `main.kt`, `test2.kt` and `test3.kt` will using `kotlin.io.println` directly.

the `test1.kt` will using the package top-level function `println`.

the `test.kt` will using the package top-level function `println` since the star import statement priority is lower than package top-level scope.

which means the function find strategy in kotlin is not bubbled, only find the top-level function in itself package. and the find strategy order is:  `local` > `enclosing` > `function` > `class` > `script` > `import statement` > `package top-level` > `star import statement` > `kotlin top-level`.

you can simply using `CTRL+B`/`CTRL+ALT+B`/`F4` at the call-site function, then you can jump to the source code which the function was actually called,for example:

```
fun foo(){
   println("bar");
   // ^--- move the cursor here and press `CTRL+B`/`CTRL+ALT+B`/`F4`
}
```