# Java. How to override method in class with private constructor

Tags: java, constructor, overriding, private, tostring

I want to override toString() method of class LocalDate. I know how to override toString() method of class with public constructor like **java.util.Date** using code like this:

```
Date date = new Date () {
   @override
   public String toString() {...}
}
```

But i cant do the same thing with class that have private constructor like **java.time.LocalDate**
Is there are any way how i can workaround this?

Comment: No, you can’t do that. The `LocalDate` class is final, meaning you cannot create any subclass. It’s also the wrong way of obtaining what you want. To format a `LocalDate` into the string of your liking use an appropriate `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Possibly related: [Localdate.format, format is not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462041/localdate-format-format-is-not-applied)

Comment: I appreciate the comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can't.

That class javadoc tells you:

> public **final** class LocalDate

You can't extend a final class, therefore you can't change the behavior of any of its methods, at least not in Java. (Kotlin offers [extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254766/kotlin-extension-for-final-class), that allow you to do "sort of" that thing).

But as pointed out in the comments, *assuming* that your problem is to properly format a Date, LocalDate, ... instance, then **overriding** `toString()` is simply the wrong approach. You turn date objects into formatted date strings by using a DateFormatter, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177370/how-to-format-localdate-to-string) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot override methods of a final class.